# Join 2 collection list together from 2 data sources find the matches and loop through the results

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, collections

I am wanting to merge together 2 different collections.

Example collection 1: (linqpad to live sql server)

```
Sample Data (collection azedIdentity):

PersonID | FirstName | LastName   |  
 3197908    John        Smith
 4444       Jody        Smith
 55555      Jon         Smither



var azedIdentity = PersonMatchNoDOBRequired("John", "Smith").AsDynamic()
    .Select (x => new FindPersonContactViewModel
    {
        PersonID = x.PersonID,
        AZEDID = x.AZEDID,
        FirstName = x.FirstName,
        MiddleName = x.MiddleName,
        LastName = x.LastName,
    }).ToList();
```

Now is where I will query a another data source ( in memory for this question)

```
var personContactRoles = new List<FindPersonContactViewModel>()
{ new FindPersonContactViewModel { PersonID = 3197908, FirstName = "John", MiddleName= "", LastName="Smith", ContactType="Farmer", ContactRoleTypeId = 1, ExistInContactManager = true, ActionType = true, IsInContactManager = true },
  new FindPersonContactViewModel { PersonID = 3197908, FirstName = "John", MiddleName= "", LastName="Smith", ContactType="Plumber", ContactRoleTypeId = 2, ExistInContactManager = true, ActionType = true, IsInContactManager = true },
  new FindPersonContactViewModel { PersonID = 3197908, FirstName = "John", MiddleName= "", LastName="Smith", ContactType="Landscaper", ContactRoleTypeId = 3, ExistInContactManager = true, ActionType = true, IsInContactManager = true },
  new FindPersonContactViewModel { PersonID = 2, FirstName = "Jon", MiddleName= "", LastName="Smither" },
  new FindPersonContactViewModel { PersonID = 4, FirstName = "Jo", MiddleName= "", LastName="Smith" },
  new FindPersonContactViewModel { PersonID = 5, FirstName = "Jody", MiddleName= "", LastName="Smith" },
  new FindPersonContactViewModel { PersonID = 6, FirstName = "Johnn", MiddleName= "", LastName="Smith" },
  new FindPersonContactViewModel { PersonID = 7, FirstName = "Jake", MiddleName= "", LastName="Smith" },
  new FindPersonContactViewModel { PersonID = 8, FirstName = "Jock", MiddleName= "", LastName="Smith" },
};
```

Things to notice   1.  PersonID of 3197908 is in here 3 times BECAUSE they have a different ContactRoleTypeId and ContactType

So thus my GOAL is to end up joining the data to have result collection like this

```
PersonID | FirstName | LastName   |  ContactRoleTypeId  | ContactType
 3197908    John        Smith                1                Farmer
 3197908    John        Smith                2                Plumber
 3197908    John        Smith                3                Landscaper
 4444       Jody        Smith
 55555      Jon         Smither
```

I was trying to join

```
 var ids = from azed in azedIdentity
                join personRole in personContactRoles on azed.PersonID equals personRole.PersonID
                select personRole;
```

I am thinking I need to have 2 nexted foreach loops ?????

Collection Poco model used for both sources is this:

```
public class FindPersonContactViewModel
{

    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string AZEDID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public int? GenderTypeId { get; set; }
    public string DOB { get; set; }
    public int ContactRoleTypeId { get; set; }
    public string ContactType { get; set; }
    public int PersonTypeId { get; set; }
    public string PreferredPhone { get; set; }
    public string PreferredEmail { get; set; }
    public string PhysicalAddress { get; set; }
    public bool ExistInContactManager { get; set; }
    public bool ActionType { get; set; }
    public bool IsInContactManager { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = from azed in azedIdentity join personRole in personContactRoles on azed.PersonID equals personRole.PersonID 
          into r1 from p in r1.DefaultIfEmpty() select 
        new FindPersonContactViewModel{PersonID = azed.PersonID, FirstName = azed.FirstName, LastName = azed.LastName,
                                      ContactRoleTypeId = p == null ? 0 : p.ContactRoleTypeId, ContactType = p == null ? "" : p.ContactType};
```

Comment: Very cool.   1. What if I also want to update/set  ExistInContactManager to True if a match, which is the 3 records that match   2. what If I also then end up needing to update all the email addresses with a 3rd data connection pull...  a for loop to run over the records?   thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve expected results with following:

```
var results = personContactRoles.Join(
    azedIdentity,
    x => x.FirstName + x.LastName,
    y => y.FirstName + y.LastName,
    (x, y) => new FindPersonContactViewModel()
    {
        PersonID = y.PersonID,
        FirstName = y.FirstName,
        LastName = y.LastName,
        ContactRoleTypeId = x.ContactRoleTypeId,
        ContactType = x.ContactType
    });
```

however you will get `0` at `ContactRoleTypeId` since your POCO `FindPersonContactViewModel.ContactRoleTypeId` is not nullable integer

Comment: Well, what I want is all the unmatched records, along with the 3 matches, sort of a concat method , but removing the 1 record since it is only in the azedIdentity.