# Need to update values in collection when combined with linq

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, collections

Previous Question:

[Join 2 collection list together from 2 data sources find the matches and loop through the results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56677478/join-2-collection-list-together-from-2-data-sources-find-the-matches-and-loop-th/56677962#56677962)

I am wanting to allow set the values of the matching to be true

```
var result = from azed in azedIdentity join personRole in personContactRoles on azed.PersonID equals personRole.PersonID 
      into r1 from p in r1.DefaultIfEmpty() select 
    new FindPersonContactViewModel
        {
            PersonID = azed.PersonID, 
            FirstName = azed.FirstName, 
            LastName = azed.LastName,
            ContactRoleTypeId = p == null ? 0 : p.ContactRoleTypeId, 
            ContactType = p == null ? "" : p.ContactType,
            //IsInContactManager = true, // I want this conditional only for the 3 that match
        };
```

Comment: Don't you just need `IsInContactManager = p != null`?

Comment: Well I didn't try that , but this works    `IsInContactManager = p == null ? false : true,`   what is the different?   what exactly on both is p null ?

Comment: so is "p" referring to the joined match?

Comment: Ok, yours works as well.   so  p != null is for the personContactRoles?  Or the match ?

Comment: DefaultIfEmpty ensures that p is null if the match fails, and not null if the match succeeds, yes